# Switch between term and shell keeping directory

Tags: dired, shell, term

I am a beginner user of emacs so please answer being aware of this.

I use dired to connect to a remote computer and navigate directories.

I sometimes want to go to a shell or terminal on the remote machine. If I type M-x term while in the dired buffer on the remote machine I get a terminal on my local machine not the directory I was viewing in dired.
However if I type M-x shell instead (I have to give my remote shell path first) then the shell opens in the same directory I was viewing in dired.

So is it possible to have M-x term open in the current dired directory and furthermore is it possible to switch from shell mode to terminal mode or vice versa while maintaining the current directory? 
ALso can I set emacs to remember where the remote shell path is so I don't have to enter this?

Comment: Not super related, but have you tried using `eshell`?(https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104325/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-eshell-and-term-in-emacs) You can definitely set up emacs to remember your path. You could `setq` a variable to hold the path, and a shortcut to call the shell command you prefer.